# Long Polling XML with PHP and JSON via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, json

I have a back-end script (`getData.php`) that works with an AJAX script to update the browser upon the changing of a time-stamp on a particular file as a means to long poll. I have gotten the script to work when polling a .txt file as it simply echos the text back to the browser verbatim. However, now I am trying to poll an XML file in which I do not want to echo verbatim; as you can see in the script below I am trying to identify parent and child nodes and echo them presented with additional HTML elements where seen fit.

```
    <?php

    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/data.xml';

    $lastmodif = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
    $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);

    while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) {
        usleep(10000);
        clearsatcache();
        $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['msg']        = SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($filename));
    $response['timestamp']      = $currentmodif;
    $data = json_encode($response);

    // Print the text portions to extract
    foreach ($data['range']['item'] as $book)
    {
        echo "<div>Book: {$book['bookname']}<p>{$book['text']}</p></div>\n";
    }

    // Print the array
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    ?>
```

Keep in mind the script was working with text files when I was simply `echo json_encode($response);` but now that I am making variable `$data = json_encode($response);` and then using `print_r($data);` it is not working. Any ideas?

Here is my sample XML file:

```
    <library>
      <book>
        <bookname>Beowulf</bookname>
        <text>This is fake, enter real text here. </text>
      </book>
      <book>
        <bookname>Old Yeller</bookname>
        <text>This is fake, enter real text here. </text>
      </book>
      <book>
        <bookname>White Fang</bookname>
        <text>This is fake, enter real text here. </text>
      </book>
    </library>
```

Comment: $data after the json_encode is an object, not anymore an array, that's why your loop don't work.

Comment: You are not using simplexmlelement correctly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Comment: @zeflex thanks for the input, but this doesn't direct the root cause or relate to the question. How can I target particular nodes and echo them? Thanks for your feed back though I will work on cleaning up the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `simplexml_load_file` and get specific nodes.

Say this is a sample xml

```
<library>
    <range>
      <item>
        <book>
          <bookname>Beowolf</bookname>
          <text>This is fake, enter real text here. </text>
        </book>
      </item>
    </range>
  </library>
```

An example

```
$xObj = simplexml_load_file($filename):
$response['bookname'] = $xObj->bookname;
```

Or Perhaps in a loop.

```
$xObj = simplexml_load_file($filename);
foreach($xObj as $book){
  echo (string)$book->bookname;
  echo "<br />";
}
```

https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file

**Update to your comment:**

```
$response = array();
foreach($xObj as $book){  
  $val = array(); 
  $val["msg"] = "<p>" . (string)$book->bookname . "</p>";
  $response[] = $val; 
}
$response["timestamp"] = "1234";

print_r($response);exit;
```

Comment: Jack, this ^ seems like it may work, however, I cannot echo the inner nodes' content for whatever reason. Would you please take a look at this snippet: http://pastebin.com/Dxv94wr9 to see what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Jack, I should add, your code with the snippet works for printing the "`<br />` and the `<p>` tags but the `$book->bookname;` seems to not be echoing.

Comment: That's because `$book->bookname` is still an object. Cast it as a string. It should echo each bookname. See my update.

Comment: Jack, that loop seemed to work for echoing, unfortunately it only prints the last node. I think the loop in my script is overwriting the prior nodes until it reaches the last node. I updated my XML (above) for a better example and here is your modified script with the described symptom: http://pastebin.com/iLrANWns .

Comment: That's because on every iteration you are clearing out the variable `$response["msg"]` so you end up with the last one. If you want each bookname to have the `msg` key you can do this. See my update.

Comment: NOTE: I used `=` inside of the loop on pastebin, but on my live test I am using `.=`, however this was not the cause of the ^ error described. The nodes' strings are still getting overwritten. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess I'm confused. are you wanting to retrieve ALL the booknames? Because that's what that does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46651/discussion-between-jim22150-and-panama-jack)